# Overlay transparent video to camera feed OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, video-streaming, video-processing, video-capture

I've been searching how to overlay transparent video to camera feed in Python (or actually in any language) and the closest thing I've seen is using `opencv`.

I followed the tutorials [here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html) and did some experiments. One is adding a new `VideoCapture` inside the `while` loop to play video from files when capturing video from camera; but the video won't show up.

Other things I came across are mixing videos and camera feed but not really doing an overlay.

I'm lost in track and any tutorials or links on how to do it programmatically are highly appreciated.

UPDATE: This is about loading the camera feed and transparent video frame-by-frame and time-by-time simultaneously.

Comment: is your question about how to load two videos synchronously frame-by-frame / time-by-time, or about how to merge two images according to some transparency information?

Comment: It is about loading two videos (camera feed and transparent video) frame-by-frame and time-by-time simultaneously. Thanks @Micka, will update the question

Comment: Share your code please.

Comment: so both videos have exactly the same framerate? Otherwise frame-by-frame and time-by-time isn't possible. Just use 2x VideoCapture and read from both videoCaptures in every iteration => loading solved.

Comment: @Micka Syncronization is possible. I am going to post the code when I finish it. Also, the camera generally does not have a framerate, rather it depends on the CPU usage at that specific time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import cv2
import time
import numpy as np

current_milli_time = lambda: int(round(time.time() * 1000))

# Camera feed
cap_cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
if not cap_cam.isOpened():
    print('Cannot open camera')
    exit()
ret, frame_cam = cap_cam.read()
if not ret:
    print('Cannot open camera stream')
    cap_cam.release()
    exit()

# Video feed
filename = 'myvideo.mp4'
cap_vid = cv2.VideoCapture(filename)
if not cap_cam.isOpened():
    print('Cannot open video: ' + filename)
    cap_cam.release()
    exit()
ret, frame_vid = cap_vid.read()
if not ret:
    print('Cannot open video stream: ' + filename)
    cap_cam.release()
    cap_vid.release()
    exit()

# Specify maximum video time in milliseconds
max_time = 1000 * cap_vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT) / cap_vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)

# Resize the camera frame to the size of the video
height = int(cap_vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
width = int(cap_vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))

# Starting from now, syncronize the videos
start = current_milli_time()

while True:
    # Capture the next frame from camera
    ret, frame_cam = cap_cam.read()
    if not ret:
        print('Cannot receive frame from camera')
        break
    frame_cam = cv2.resize(frame_cam, (width, height), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

    # Capture the frame at the current time point
    time_passed = current_milli_time() - start
    if time_passed > max_time:
        print('Video time exceeded. Quitting...')
        break
    ret = cap_vid.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, time_passed)
    if not ret:
        print('An error occured while setting video time')
        break
    ret, frame_vid = cap_vid.read()
    if not ret:
        print('Cannot read from video stream')
        break

    # Blend the two images and show the result
    tr = 0.3 # transparency between 0-1, show camera if 0
    frame = ((1-tr) * frame_cam.astype(np.float) + tr * frame_vid.astype(np.float)).astype(np.uint8)
    cv2.imshow('Transparent result', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27: # ESC is pressed
        break

cap_cam.release()
cap_vid.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: This approach skips the frames of the video between the time passed at one loop. Since the camera does not have a constant frame rate, you need to mark the video frames and repeat the camera frames **after** the real-time operation in order not to overburden the process, if you want frame-by-frame result.